# add_foreign_key not creating foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-5

Im using Rails 5.1 and SQLite. The below migration is not working as expected.

```
class AddJobTitleForeignKeyToTimeOffTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    add_column :time_off_types, :job_title_id, :integer
    add_foreign_key :time_off_types, :job_title, :column => :job_title_id
  end
end
```

It creates the column "job_title_id" in the table "time_off_types" but it does not create the foreign key.

Comment: `job_title_id` is the foreign key here. `add_foreign_key` will create a foreign key mapping between the `job_title_id` column in `time_off_types` table and the id column of the 'job_titles` table on the database level. [Here](http://sevenseacat.net/posts/2015/add_foreign_key-gotchas-in-rails-4-2/) is an useful blog post on this topic

Comment: @KarthikRavichandran what you explained is exactly what I want it to do but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the first column for ? just do the second line : `add_foreign_key :time_off_types, :job_titles`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord's `add_foreign_key` method is used outside table creation, hence uses `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ...`.

SQLite's [`ALTER TABLE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) does not support adding constraints (of any kind).  (It is worth reviewing, as `ALTER TABLE` in SQLite might be more limited than you expect. For example, SQLite < `3.25.0` cannot rename columns either.)

However, SQLite `CREATE TABLE` **does** support foreign key constraints and the ActiveRecord migration `create_table` `#references` method can create them:

```
def change
  create_table :pets do
    t.references :owner, foreign_key: true
    ...
  end
end
```

The Rails Migrations Guide does not mention this difference.

So how does this work?

ActiveRecord database adapters have two methods: `supports_foreign_keys?` and `supports_foreign_keys_in_create?` which are both `false` by default (see the Rails API documentation).

`add_foreign_key` [returns immediately](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb#L924) unless `supports_foreign_keys?` is `true`, but it is `false` for SQLite, so end of the trail for `add_foreign_key`.

On the other hand, [`supports_foreign_keys_in_create?` is `true`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite3_adapter.rb#L126-L128) for SQLite >= `3.6.19`, which allows the `#references` method to create the foreign key using `CREATE TABLE ...`.

(I've linked to Rails 5.1 code, as that's what you were using at the time of the question, but this all remains true as of Rails 5.2.1 today.)

Comment: hmm... I'm using ActiveRecord 5.2, with sqlite 3.27.2 and it doesn't appear to add foreign key constraints in the SQL schema nor is it reflected in schema.rb. `supports_foreign_keys?` returns `false` and `supports_foreign_keys_in_create` returns `true` as you say. But even though I use `t.references` in `create_table` it doesn't appear to generate the correct SQL for the table...

Comment: Turns out, there's a bug in the `sqlite3` adapter that will lose the foreign key when the table is altered: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33520
Appear to be a fix in, but I _think_ it's targeted for v6.